# windows-curses not working with an import error

Tags: python, curses

I'm just doing some testing with windows-curses (2.3.0) and I was using this code and it gave me an error. The code and error are below.

Code:

```py
import curses
from curses import wrapper

def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.addstr("Hello World")
    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getch()

wrapper(main)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\norbe\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Testing\Curses\curses.py", line 1, in <module>
    import curses
  File "C:\Users\norbe\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Testing\Curses\curses.py", line 2, in <module>
    from curses import wrapper
ImportError: cannot import name 'wrapper' from partially initialized module 'curses' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code already imported `curses` and its context (methods and variables) binded to it.
It means that `wrapper` is already identified by python.

Try this :

```
import curses
wrapper = curses.wrapper
```

Comment: New Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\norbe\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Testing\Curses\curses.py", line 1, in <module>
    import curses
  File "C:\Users\norbe\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Testing\Curses\curses.py", line 2, in <module>
    wrapper = curses.wrapper
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'curses' has no attribute 'wrapper' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: I actually install the library and works fine even with your code. Please update your post with your os and python specification and the way you install the library. And I think it is not the whole program, if it is possible post the your code as much as possible.

Comment: The error was on my part, I had the file name curses.py which was breaking the code

Comment: THIS: @LegosAndStuff "... I had the file name curses.py..." same issue with me. Solved thanks!